# Replace "a", "an", "the" with blank space in a text file

Tags: c, text-files

A friend of mine gave me a task to write a program to

> replace "a", "an", "the" with blank space in a text file in C.

I wrote that program, but that went too lengthy as I checked "a", "an", "the" individually.

For example, I replaced `"a"` by

NOTE: `fs` is pointer to the source file and `ft` is pointer to the target file.

```
while(fgets(str, 100, fs) != NULL)
{
    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] ==  ' '  ||
            str[i] ==  '.'  ||
            str[i] ==  ','  ||
            str[i] ==  '\n' ||
            str[i] ==  '\t')
        {
            if (str[i+1] == 'a' || str[i+1] == 'A')
            {
                if (str[i+2] == ' '  ||
                    str[i+2] == '.'  ||
                    str[i+2] == ','  ||
                    str[i+2] == EOF  ||
                    str[i+2] == '\0' ||
                    str[i+2]==  '\n' ||
                    str[i+2]==  '\t')
                {
                    str[i+1]=' ';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fputs(str,ft);
}
```

Is there a shorter way to do the same?

Take care of the fact that `"a"`, `"an"`, `"the"` can be the first words in the source file.

Comment: What do you want as output if the file contains: _"a" in double quotes, or the sentence ends with 'the.'_? It looks as though the code needs to be case-insensitive.

Comment: I think not go for `c` language for it.use `sed` command in linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `fscanf` and `fprintf` functions so that scanning the file would be easy for you and you can easily check for 'a, an, the':

```
char s[50];
while(fscanf(fp, "%s", s) != EOF) 
{
    if(strcmp(s, "a") == 0 || strcmp(s, "an") == 0 || strcmp(s, "the") == 0)
    {
        char c = ' ';
        fprintf(ft, "%s", c);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(ft, "%s", s); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't handle lines longer than 100 chars correctly, and using fscanf doesn't help that at all.

Comment: `if(s=="a"||s=="an"||s=="the")` What do you mean by that??

Comment: oh, `string`  this question is tagged `C` , not tagged `C++`

Comment: Also, the task says: "replace "a", "an", "the" with blank space in a text file in c."

Comment: s contains one word scanned from file and i m checking whether that word is 'a an or the'

Comment: @MohiniMhetre: I think we can not compare strings with `==`, we have to use strcmp()

Comment: We can not compare C++ objects with strcmp either, they are not in C, I don't get it

Comment: @BuellaGábor: `s` and `a`,`an`,`the` are string literals. They are pointers to their first character, so we can not use `==`

Comment: @kevin gomes what do you mean by `s` is a string literal? "a", "an", "the" are string literals

Comment: @BuellaGábor : I simply means that they are strings, and they can not be compared using `==`

Comment: @BuellaGábor : `"demo"` is a pointer to `d`, and hence `==` can not be used

Comment: Yes, `"demo"` is a pointer to `d` . By the way, using `string s` now makes me think @MohiniMhetre confuses C with C++

Comment: I just forgot that we dnt use == to cmpare str...now i edited my code

Comment: I see, as a note, the condition will always be true, as it would only be false if `s` starts with both `a` ; `an` ; `the` Remeber, strcmp returns `0` for equal strings, non-zero for non-equal strings

Comment: Also, this code can easily crash, with a word longer than 50 characters resulting in a buffer overflow

Comment: @MohiniMhetre : you gave me a good hint, but your code is wrong

Comment: actually i have not used c lang for long time so maybe my code syntax is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can read the input char-by-char, using for example getchar, or always remember the last few chars, even if they were in the previous buffer. This way you need to remember the previous two chars, and the current char in a little "rolling-array", that you would reset at each word boundary.

Using a fixed sized buffer with fgets, or fscanf, you need a lot of codeing to handle special cases. There are a few, for example the lines don't start with space or tab, but a line parhaps starts with "the". In that case, there will be no such character before the word. The same thing is true about whitespace following a word. You can get around these things by allocating a bit more space for the buffer, fill the first char with ' ' , and call fgets this way:

```
 fgets(str + 1, 99, fs)
```

But you still have the problem of words at boundaries, where your buffer ends with "... t" and the next fgets gives you "he ..." . 
Just keep an array of 3 chars, and the current length of the array, resetting the length to zero at each word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code works for a reasonably plausible definition of the problem:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static char const *words[] = { "a", "the", "an" };
enum { NUM_WORDS = sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]) };

static void mapword(char *word, int len)
{
    char lower[256];
    word[len] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
        lower[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_WORDS; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(words[i], lower) == 0)
        {
            putchar(' ');
            return;
        }
    }
    fputs(word, stdout);
}

int main(void)
{
    char word[256];
    int c;
    size_t nletters = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        /*
        ** This would break if you enter a word with 256 characters
        ** ending in 'a' because the word would be split after 255
        ** characters and the trailing 'a' would then match the
        ** next buffer full, which is an awfully improbable event.
        */
        if (!isalpha(c) || nletters >= sizeof(word)-1)
        {
            if (nletters > 0)
            {
                mapword(word, nletters);
                nletters = 0;
            }
            putchar(c);
        }
        else
            word[nletters++] = c;
    }

    if (nletters > 0)
    {
        /*
        ** Since a text file should end with a newline, the program
        ** should not get here!
        */
        mapword(word, nletters);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example, given the first three lines of the question as input:

```
A friend of mine gave me a task to write a program to
replace "a", "an", "the" with blank space in a text file in c.
I wrote that program but that went too lengthy as I checked "a", "an", "the" individually.
```

the output from the program is:

```
  friend of mine gave me   task to write   program to
replace " ", " ", " " with blank space in   text file in c.
I wrote that program but that went too lengthy as I checked " ", " ", " " individually.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some `system` command then your life is easy. `sed` is  linux command to serve your requirement.

You can do as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    system("sed 's/an//g;s/a//g;s/the//g' file");
}
```

If `file` contain

```
replace “a”, “an”, “the” with blank space in a text file
```

Output is

```
replce “”, “”, “” with blk spce in  text file
```

**Caution** : This code replace space every where when it found matching pattern.So it not check for matching whole word.